# Package error that moves when saving source files

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I've started building a small web app with Go in VS Code and I keep getting this error on the package line:

```
can't load package: package fantasy_stats: found packages jsontest (jsontest.go) and main (main.go) in /home/scott/programming/golang/src/fantasy_stats
```

What's strange is whenever I save one of my 3 source files, the error disappears from the other files and appears in the most recently saved file.

My `$GOPATH` is set to `$HOME/programming/golang` and the 3 files are in the directory shown in the error: `$HOME/programming/golang/src/fantasy_stats`.  Two of the files (`main.go` and `results_handler.go`) are `package main` and the one other (`jsontest.go`) is `package jsontest` (this is just a tiny side program to generate test data and isn't used in the other files).  `func main()` is also only in `main.go` for the `package main` files.  Renaming `main.go` to `fantasy_stats.go` has no effect on the error.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: One folder == exactly one package. Do **not** put different packages into one folder. Never. Read How to Write Go Code and stick to it.

Comment: @Volker is right. Read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).